# Test a REST Endpoint with AES Encrypted data

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

Environment: Java 8 / SpringBoot v2.0.2

I'm trying to fix a security issue in the code by changing Cipher instance from just "AES" to "AES/GCM/NoPadding". However, the existing test for the REST endpoint which has an encrypted path parameter value which uses this encrypt method fails.

Here is my encrypt method,

```
public String encrypt(final Long transactionId) {
    Assert.notNull(transactionId, "Transaction Id Should Not Be null");
    String encryptedText = "";
    try
    {   final byte[] encodedSecretKey = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptKey);
        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedSecretKey, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(1, secretKey);
        final byte[] contentAsBytes = transactionId.toString().getBytes();
        byte[] contentAsByteCypherText = cipher.doFinal(contentAsBytes);

        byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
        byte[] message = new byte[NUMBER_OF_IV_BYTES + contentAsByteCypherText.length];
        System.arraycopy(iv, SRC_POSITION, message, DEST_POSITION, NUMBER_OF_IV_BYTES);
        System.arraycopy(contentAsByteCypherText, SRC_POSITION, message, NUMBER_OF_IV_BYTES, contentAsByteCypherText.length);
        encryptedText = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(message);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to encrypt Transaction ID ", e);
        throw new BlahException("Failed to encrypt transaction id", e);
    }
    return encryptedText;
}
```

My Test

```
public void testJourney(final Long transactionId) throws Exception {
    final String request = loadExpectedContent(transactionId);
    mockRestServiceServer.reset();
    mockRestServiceServer.expect(requestTo("/spring/rest/transaction/" + webClient.encrypt(transactionId)))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(withSuccess().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(request));
    final CompletableFuture<String> completable = webClient.getWebJourney(transactionId);
    mockRestServiceServer.verify();
    final String response = completable.get();
    Assert.assertNotNull(response);
    LOGGER.info(LoggingUtils.format(LoggingUtils.keyValue("Request", transactionId),
            LoggingUtils.keyValue("Response", LoggingUtils.parse(response))));
}
```

In this test the encrypt method is hit twice.

1. when trying to create the expect
2. inside webClient.getWebJourney(transactionId)

The difference is when `Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");` is used those two times it returns two different values failing the test. But when `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` is used (without IV) it returns same value both times.

My question is how can I test this REST endpoint with "AES/GCM/NoPadding"?

Comment: `messsage` is currently filled but not used, i.e. the IV is probably not sent to the receiver. `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` uses ECB by default, perhaps your REST endpoint only supports this mode.

Comment: When using GCM mode, it's required that the IV is different with each encryption - if not the encryption is completely broken. At the same time using an IV will give you different ciphertext with each encryption - this is sort of the purpose of the IV.

Answer (score 0):

To test it you don't want to get the same ciphertext, you want to get the same cleartext after decryption. With GCM you want a test that encrypts something twice and doesn't get the same result.

You should not re-use IV values (with GCM the same IV and cleartext results in the same ciphertext).

So this:

```java
        byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
```

Will return a secure random generated array of 12 bytes, hence the ciphertext is different each time.

Calling `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` without IV is definitely not what you want to do:

- it's likely defaulting to ECB, which is old and [badly broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)  (have a look at the penguin in the "encrypted" image.
- not using an IV is why you get the same result - the idea of the IV is to start with some randomness to avoid repeating patterns that can be used to find the key.

I would change the test to perform encryption, then decrypt (in the test) and ensure the ciphertext is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already have following test in place,
1) encrypt -> decrypt - assert that the decrypted text is the same as original one
2) encrypt twice with the same key - assert that the ciphertext produced each time is different 

What I'm trying to achieve is to test the endpoint with an encrypted path variable

Comment: Right.. why are you encrypting the transactionId, if it's already encrypted?

Comment: I don't encrypt an already encrypted transactionId. It's just that, in this test the encrypt method webClient.encrypt(transactionId) is hit twice.


1)when trying to create the expect
2)inside webClient.getWebJourney(transactionId)


Since, the ciphertext generated is different each time it is hit, the existing unit test fails. My task is to find a way to test this end point